# handle external volume keys in J2me

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp, mmapi

Can you please give me some idea about why S40 device does not get external volume key events?

I have this phone:

1. Nokia 5130 XpressMusic - Series 40 5th Edition, Feature Pack 1
2. Nokia 3110 Classic. - Series 40 3rd Edition, Feature Pack 2

Both devices have external volume key but don't know why it's not working.

I tried below link which explain S40 5th edition FP1 support. So in my case Nokia 5130 not working. Why?

[External volume keys - Nokia Java Developer site](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/implementation-notes/jsr-135-mobile-media-api/runtime-environment-notes/external-volume-keys.html)

[MIDlet volume control in Series 40 and S60 devices - Nokia developer wiki](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/MIDlet_volume_control_in_Series_40_and_S60_devices)

Answer (score 1):

In J2ME you can not get external key event for volume keys. It depends upon manufacture and there is no list for that in J2ME.

Comment: Yes Right, I think its depends upon manufacture. Becoz, I am not getting any proper solution to handle external volume. But I am stuck with nokia 5130 xpressmusic. This device have S40 5th edition fp1 then also not working(link in my above question.). Why?

Comment: In Nokia 5130 or any other device you are not able to get the external  volume key event.

Comment: Yes right. If I run that code in N72 then it work properly. But not with Nokia 5130. U knw why?

Comment: On N72 are you able to get external key event?Which event are you getting for the N72? and it is device to device very you can not find solution for this.

Comment: Ohh... Sorry its my mistake. I am doing testing Nokia N78 not N72. Sorry for my wrong post.